# Deleting columns with specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe output from the python script which gives following output

|  | Datetime | High | Low | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 546 | 2021-06-15 14:30:00 | 15891.049805 | 15868.049805 | 14:30:00 |
| 547 | 2021-06-15 14:45:00 | 15883.000000 | 15869.900391 | 14:45:00 |
| 548 | 2021-06-15 15:00:00 | 15881.500000 | 15866.500000 | 15:00:00 |
| 549 | 2021-06-15 15:15:00 | 15877.750000 | 15854.549805 | 15:15:00 |
| 550 | 2021-06-15 15:30:00 | 15869.250000 | 15869.250000 | 15:30:00 |

i Want to remove all rows where time is equal to 15:30:00. tried different things but unable to do.
Help please.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw

ticker = "^NSEI"
# getting Intraday data for plotting 15 minutes and 75 minutes chart
en = dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=1)
st = en - dt.timedelta(days=30)
df = yf.download(ticker,start = st, end=en, interval = '15m')\
.drop(['Open', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'], axis = 1).reset_index()
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'].astype(str).str[:-6])
df['Time'] = df['Datetime'].dt.time


print(df)
```

Comment: df[~df['Time'] == "15:30:00"]

Comment: This is what you looking for `df[~df['Time'].str.contains('15:30:00')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pandas also provides vectorized string operations across the dataframe, thus it's easy to get the rows those contain the string:

**Data-Frame**

```
>>> df
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
4  6/15/2021 15:30  15869.25000  15869.25000  15:30:00
```

**Result:**

**Method One:**

Using `str.contains` ...

```
>>> df[~df['Time'].str.contains('15:30:00')]
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

OR

if you are looking based on the `Datetime`

```
>>> df[~df['Datetime'].str.contains('15:30')]
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

OR

```
>>> df[~df.Time.str.contains("15:30") == True]
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

OR

```
>>> df[df['Time'].str.contains('15:30') == False]
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

OR

```
>>> df[df['Time'].str.contains('15:30') == 0]
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

**Method two:**

Using `isin` ...

```
>>> df[~df['Time'].isin(['15:30:00'])]
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

**Method three:**

Using `Not equal to of dataframe and other, element-wise (binary operator ne).`

```
>>> df[df.Time != '15:30:00']
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

OR

```
>>> df[df['Time'] != '15:30:00']
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

OR

```
>>> df[df['Time'].ne('15:30:00')]
          Datetime         High          Low      Time
0  6/15/2021 14:30  15891.04981  15868.04981  14:30:00
1  6/15/2021 14:45  15883.00000  15869.90039  14:45:00
2  6/15/2021 15:00  15881.50000  15866.50000  15:00:00
3  6/15/2021 15:15  15877.75000  15854.54981  15:15:00
```

Comment: Thanks Mate. Method one not working for me. Others worked. Error in Method one . "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: Good to hear, happy coding!

Comment: Maybe Worth trying `df[~df['Time'].astype(str).str.contains('15:30:00')]`

Answer (score 2):

The way I did was the following,

First we get the the time we want to remove from the dataset, that is 15:30:00 in this case.

Since the Datetime column is in the datetime format, we cannot compare the time as strings. So we convert the given time in the datetime.time() format.

`rm_time = dt.time(15,30)`

With this, we can go about using the `DataFrame.drop()`

`df.drop(df[df.Datetime.dt.time == rm_time].index)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

test_data=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
test_data=test_data[test_data["Time"]!="15:30:00"]
print(test_data)
```

Just select rows based on condition.